# AutoFac Exception after upgrading NServiceBus

Tags: nservicebus, autofac

I just upgraded NServiceBus from 4.6 to 5.0

I did the steps suggested in the "4 to 5" document and am able to compile. Now I receive the following Error:

> None of the constructors found with
>   'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
>   'Nop.Web.Controllers.ShoppingCartController' can be invoked with the
>   available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter
>   'NServiceBus.IBus bus' of constructor 'Void .ctor(NServiceBus.IBus, ...

What has to be done?

(Update: My Configuration)

```
public static class ServiceBus
    {
        public static void Init(ILifetimeScope scope)
        {

            var configuration = new BusConfiguration();
            configuration.EndpointName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceBusEndpointName"]);
            configuration.UseTransport<MsmqTransport>();
            configuration.UseSerialization<JsonSerializer>();
            configuration.UsePersistence<RavenDBPersistence>();
            configuration.DisableFeature<Sagas>();
            configuration.Transactions().Enable();
            configuration.AssembliesToScan(AllAssemblies
                .Matching("Nop.Services.dll")
                .And("TengoMessages.dll")
                .And("Partner.Pricing.Messages.dll")
                .And("Partner.Pricing.Infrastructure.dll"));
            configuration.UseContainer<AutofacBuilder>();
            configuration.PurgeOnStartup(false);

            var bus  = Bus.Create(configuration);
            bus.Start();


            var newBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
            newBuilder.RegisterInstance(bus);
            newBuilder.Update(Singleton<IContainer>.Instance);        
        }
```

Comment: Not sure how this could have worked befire. In NSB 4, when using yoru own container, you must pass it as a parameter to the configurator. I am quite qurious about your thinking here, if you don't NServiceBus know about your container, how possibly it could resolve your dependencies?

Comment: After weeks of bugfixing we decided to roll back our project and stay with version 4.6

Comment: The issue is very easy to fix. The documentation says exactly what you need to do http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/containers

Comment: @OleAlbers same situation here! The actual error thrown is : DeclaringMethod = error CS0433: The type 'Service' exists in both 'Autofac, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da' and 'NServiceBus.Core, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c'

now I wonder how to fix this...

Answer (score 0):

I don't use AutoFac, so I'm not familiar with the ContainerBuilder concept, but it looks like you want to use an existing container with NServiceBus?

Create the instance of your container first, and then change your configuration code to use:

```
configuration.UseContainer<AutofacBuilder>(customizations =>
 customizations.ExistingContainer(container));
```

It looks like the second to last line of code is registering the bus--this should not be necessary, as the above code will ensure all NSB-related classes get properly registered.